# Converting an array of values to string

Tags: php

`array = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,1]`

rearrange the value to new array

`SS (5), S (4), TP (3), TS (2), STS (1)`

`newarray =[sts,ts,tp,s,ss,tp,ts,tp,sts]`

i have try using switch but it did not work as it should.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Comment: Help with what? What problem are you having?

Comment: Make an effort...Read a book

Comment: some hint from you guys just help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are using PHP 5.3 or above, see Deepu's answer above.**

If not, see http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Now using that link you could loop through your array and convert them.

```
$array = array(5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2);
$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $new[] = onvert_number_to_words($value);
}

print_r($new); // array = ('five','four','three','two','one','four','three','two')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) for PHP.

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(123);
```

Produces the result: one hundred twenty-three

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array_map(function ($num) {
    static $map = array(1 => 'one', /* more numbers here ... */);
    return $map[$num];
}, $array);
```

Or using Deepu's suggestion:

```
$newArray = array_map(array(new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT), 'format'), $array);
```